# Cannot finish Wagtail install (No such file or directory)

Tags: wagtail

I am running virtualenv on a Mac and have successfully created a new MySite directory. Now I want to follow the remaining instructions:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ ./manage.py migrate
$ ./manage.py createsuperuser
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error:

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I checked that Django and Pillow are properly installed. They are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To do a clean wagtail install on a Mac simply do this:

```
→ virtualenv-3.4 ~/installation_test # installed via sudo port install py34-virtualenv
→ source ~/installation_test/bin/activate
→ pip install wagtail
→ wagtail start my_site
→ cd my_site/
→ python manage.py migrate
→ python manage.py runserver
```